# Big O when stacking containers

Tags: c++, stl, big-o

I use a std::map which is implemented as red-black tree with time complexity of O(log(N)) for access (according to this site: http://bigocheatsheet.com/). How do I calculate the big O if I stack these containers.

For example `map<int, map<int, int>>`. What is the big O for accessing the innermost map?

Comment: *stack these containers* means?

Comment: It is the same.  A `map<int, map<int, int>>` is no different from a `map<int, int>` as far as accessing the key.

Comment: Your question needs to be formulated more precisely. What do you need to access? What assumptions can you make on the existing coefficients? For example, do all maps have the same size? Does any map have keys in `[0,1,..N]` where `N` is the size?

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon True, I should mention that I want to access the inner most map. But I think, when talking about big O, the size is always assumed to converge towards infinity. Am I wrong?

Comment: Suppose you want to lookup the key `j` within an inner most map, and that only one of them has such a key but you don't know which one. This completely changes the way you have to think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to sum the complexities in this case,

```
map<int, map<int, int>> data;
const auto& lookup = data[5]; // here you spend O(logn)
int value lookup2 = lookup[3]; // here you spend O(logn)
```

So it's *O(logn)* + *O(logn)* = *O(klogn)* = *O(logn)*.

This would be *O(logn)* also in case of `map<int, map<int, map<int, map<int, ..` and so on because the amount of nested levels doesn't depend on `N` but they are always constant.

Answer (score 3):

Same thing. If have `map<int, map<int, int>> m` and you want to look up `m[4][2]` - that's just two, independent map lookups. So you just add them: `O(log M + log N) = O(log MN)` where `M` is the size of the outer map and `N` is the size of the inner map.

Note that the outer and inner map sizes are independent.

Comment: good point that the complexity is dependent on both sizes - the outer and inner collection, however I'm not sure if `O` notation allows to use 2D domain...

Comment: Does it make a difference if the inner maps are of differing sizes, or can you just take N = the average size? I haven't done formal complexity analysis for a long time, and it's amazing how much you forget in just a couple of decades.

Comment: @W.F. Of course it does. If you have two independent variables you need to both. e.g. Dijkstra's algorithm is `O(E + VlgV)`.

Comment: @molbdnilo In this case since we're just adding I would take the max size.

Comment: @Barry all in all, why shouldn't one use two variables in `O`. Good point, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Still `O(Log(N))`

Assuming you meant accessing the second map within the out map, it's essentially two O(log(N)) operations back to back.  Hence `O(2*log(N))`, which reduced down is `O(log(N))` again.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same, O(log(N)).

This is because you have O(log(N)) to get the 'inner' map, then you need O(log(N)) again for the element, so in total you have O(2*log(N)) which is the same as O(log(N)).